# Using Parse, Unity 3D, C# and can not access the objectId of a row

Tags: c#, parsing, unity-game-engine

My code:

```
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseObject.GetQuery (“tokens”)
        .WhereEqualTo ("createdBy", “XXXXsEwdZ”)
        .Limit (10)
        .OrderBy (“tokenName");
    query.FindAsync ().ContinueWith (t =>
                                     {
        IEnumerable<ParseObject> results = t.Result;

        foreach (var record in results) 
        {
            tokenName = record.Get<string> ("tokenName");  
            //tokenObjectId = record.Get<string> ("objectId");

            Debug.Log(tokenName + " : " + tokenObjectId);

        }
```

the loop works long as the commented line remains commented out.

what's really annoying is that no one else has asked a similar question before.  :-/

Thanks in advance for the help and thanks to all who have asked and answered before me. i benefited as well

Comment: What error do you receive? How does the input you are parsing look? How does ParseObject look? Do both the input and ParseObject have objectId?

Comment: I receive no error.  Just no output.  When the line is commented out it prints the tokenNames.  Each row of the class has an objectId when viewed in the parse data browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the commented out line should read :

tokenObjectId = record.ObjectId;

from https://parse.com/docs/unity_guide#objects-retrieving

The three special values are provided as properties:

string objectId = gameScore.ObjectId;

DateTime? updatedAt = gameScore.UpdatedAt;

DateTime? createdAt = gameScore.CreatedAt;